# Valgrind with multi-threaded applications

Tags: soap, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am testing a web server that uses gSoap.  I run it under valgrind and I get a memory leak report in a few seconds.  However, I would like to test services that are invoked by a remote client and I cannot get valgrind to report on errors after startup.  Can valgrind be used to check memory during specific operations run well after startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you receive a leak report after a few seconds, it means
that the program you launched exited after a few seconds, as by default
a leak search is only done when your program exits.

So, probably the web server is launched indirectly by the first program.
You might then need to (at least) use --trace-children=yes
to ensure the 'real' web server is running under valgrind.

Once this is done, you can launch 'on demand' leak search from a shell.
See e.g. http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.monitor-commands for details.